# Change Desktop Shortcuts Destination to SharePoint Online

Tags: powershell, shared-folders, windows-server, sharepoint

We have a client that we will be migrating to SharePoint online. Currently they have shared folders on a local server.

Users on the domain have created shortcuts to locations within the shares.

I need a PowerShell script that will change the destination of the shortcuts to a URL so when they click their File Share shortcuts, they are directed to the SharePoint online page (just a URL) instead of their old Share location.

I have a RMM platform where I can push out the scripts for all PCs on the domain so it can be a local level script, but it needs to specifiy on shortcuts on the desktop. Or even a specific shortcut (a filename variable maybe?).

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with .lnk/ShortCut files (list or change) you'll need to get WindowsScriptHost as a ComObject.

I'd start by doing an inventory what you have.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\21\SO_1439438.ps1

$OWsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Desktop = [environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')

$DesktopLinks = Get-ChildItem -Path $Desktop *.lnk | ForEach-Object {
    $OWsh.CreateShortcut($_.FullName)
}
$DesktopLinks | Out-Gridview
$DesktopLinks | Export-Csv $Desktop\DesktopLinks.csv  -NoTYpeInformation
```

The same ComObject can be used to change settings, but you'll need to transform your target's with a table, or whatsoever.